# java multidimensional array remove empty/null elements

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an `object[][]` and the inner and outer array contains `null` or empty values.

I need to remove all the empty and `null` values from those arrays.

I have tried several solutions, for example this solution  which i modified from another stack overflow post:

```
public static void Compact(object[][] array)
{
    List<Object[]> outerList = new ArrayList<Object[]>(array.length);
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        Object[] inner = array[i];
        if (inner != null) {
            List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(inner.length);
            for(int j=0; j < inner.length; j++){
                if(inner[j] != null || !"".equals(inner[j])){
                    list.add(inner[j]);
                }
            }
            outerList.add(list.toArray(new Object[list.size()]));
        }
    }
    array = outerList.toArray(new Object[outerList.size()][]);
}
```

However I cannot manage to remove the empty values. It also removes only the `null` values from the inner array.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: You forgot about ")" : "if(inner[j] != null || !"".equals(inner[j]))"

Comment: what do mean by remove a null value from an array? do you want to resize the array to only contain valid objects/values? You either have a value at some index or it's null at that index.

Comment: where is array defined/created in your code? it seems to be the driving force behind this entire code...

Comment: sry, i forgot to copy the whole code..I editet my question

Comment: You should change "object" in "Compact(Object[][] array)"

Comment: Your best shot is to change everything to String, arrays and Lists. This way you will not be accidentally  comparing "" to other types that can't be empty

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many elements you have to process, you may want to make use of Java 8's fork join pool. If not, remove the `.parallel()` in the following example code:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Compact {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[][] objects = {
      new Object[]{"Hello", null, null, "World"},
      new Object[]{null, null, ""},
      new Object[]{},
      null,
      new Object[]{new Object()},
      new Object[]{"Hello", "StackOverflow", null},
    };

    List<List<Object>> result = compact(objects);
    System.out.println(result);
  }

  private static List<List<Object>> compact(Object[][] array) {
    return Stream.of(array).parallel()
      // Ignore null objects of the outer array
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      // Process all inner arrays
      .map(inner -> Stream.of(inner).parallel()
        // Ignore null objects or empty strings
        .filter(element -> element != null && !"".equals(element))
        // Collect what is left
        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
      // From the result above, ignore all empty arrays
      .filter(inner -> !inner.isEmpty())
      // Collect what is left
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[[Hello, World], [java.lang.Object@6d9c638], [Hello, StackOverflow]]
```

Comment: thx for the answer, however i cannot use java 8 in my project, therefore I am not used writing java 8 code. I would appreciate it if you could code it in java 7 (of course if its is not too compicated and time consuming)...I will trry to understand it and write it in java 7

Comment: Certainly not if you downvote a perfectly fine solution after not specifying that you're bound to Java 7 which has been end of life for almost a year now.

Comment: I did not vote it down, or I did not intend to vote it down, i just saw it after you mention it, but you are right, I forgot to mention it at the beginning. Thx very much for you effort doing it in java 8

Comment: Ok sorry, then it probably was `efekctive` who thinks my code does not solve your problem

Comment: @javaEE-Newbie Yes, it was me by mistake. I realized that I voted the OP after the half hour limit. I do not want the points. Just check your code. Leaving structures so wide will cause you headaches. Generics are meant to narrow down from Object

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you describe. It is not possible.

Based on the description you have given and the example code, it appears that the array itself is what you want to remove all empty or null values from and that the ArrayList is merely part of your attempt at creating such an array. That is the thought process which prompts my answer.

When you create an array with length N (ie: new Object[N]), that array is initially "empty" in that it contains N null values. Example: `new Object[3]` provides array `{null, null, null}`. You cannot remove these null values, and the way arrays work "removal" doesn't even really make sense.

Using the above example of `new Object[3]`, let's say you wanted to remove element `array[1]`; after removing the null value, what would you expect to be left in `array[1]`? `null` being in that spot basically **is** the spot being empty. Would you hope that removing `array[1]` would leave you with an array of 2 elements now instead of 3? Arrays do not work that way. If you want that behavior, then you need to stick with an ArrayList instead of an array.

If you want the removal of `array[1]` to leave you with an array of length 2, then simply make your input and output to your method be an ArrayList and do not use an array at all. Do that instead of your current code that inputs an array, converts it to an ArrayList, then converts it back to an array.

The length of an array is constant. Once the array is created, it has a set number of elements, and that number cannot be changed. This is true for many programming languages. For example, C++ works the same. If your misunderstanding of arrays is because of another language that you are coming from, know that in cases like Visual Basic every time you "redimension" an array it actually throws away the array you were working with and creates a new one, and in languages which don't even require you to redimension an array but still allow you to change its size, those languages generally either do the same thing as Visual Basic or they implement the language's arrays as an ArrayList (to put it back into Java terms again).